Systemctl is unable to detect input device (bluetooth microphone), but script works manually
I'm building the google assistant on an old raspberry pi (running on Raspberry Pi OS) with a bluetooth speaker including a microphone:
The script itself consists only of activating the env and calling google assistant demo with the corresponding job id etc.
I'm able to ask and receive answers, if executing the script from the command line.
However, for the systemctl service file, it is failing and I get the status
[FATAL:audio_input_stream.cc(47)] Input device could not be opened: default
This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the input device (microphone).
pacmd list-sources
shows that my bluetooth speaker is indeed the default, and I've checked for the audio profile issues (profile for the speaker/mic is on HSP), so I don't know where the issue is. I'd be really happy, if anybody has some input (pun intended).

I've found an issue on GitHub like your issue :
https://github.com/gauravsacc/MMM-GoogleAssistant/issues/72

I found the reason, because when I run MMM, assistant.py already run.
And I run assistant.py again, mic was used by the first time, so
nothing error. And finally MMM run(at the same time I run
assistant.py???The first time assistant.py was run by MMM, and after I
killed python, it cannot run automatically). The experience is bad.
Most of time it cannot get what I said.

Try it and say us the result :)

I've seen that discussion before but honestly don't think it's a similar issue or I'm not understanding the text correctly. There is no equivalent program to MMM in my project
